# simple jquery lightbox for displaying images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

I cant believe I am asking this - but I spend the last TWO HOURS looking for a simple jquery lightbox to give to my students to learn how to implement...

What I need is something that is very simple:

I have a bunch of images and when I click on them I need a lightbox to open with a (different) image that I can specify...I just cant find anything that does simply that. Of course the lightbox will need to behave like a standard lightbox (X- close button, scale to size of image, have a line of caption or so)

something like:

```
$('.this-image').click(function(){
    awesomelightbox.open('new url');
})
```

Most of the lightboxes I checked open either the same image that was clicked, or has a gazillion options that my students wont understand.

I tried:

```
 - LightBox
 - ColorBox 
 - FancyBox 
 - VisualLightbox 
 - Featherlight
```

Nothing suits my requirement :(

Does anyone know any simple lightbox that does what I mentioned? I would greatly appreciated any pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, using Fancybox you can do it. I went to their ["How To"](http://fancybox.net/howto) and they have an example. Look at the last bit of code on the page. If you are only trying to display 2 different images you can use their method. Notice how they have a small.jpg and a big.jpg, so it essence they are using 2 different images. This way they can use one image for thumbnail and a larger one for the actual fancy box. Is this what you are looking for?

EDIT: Or if you would like to use my plugin you are welcome to source it from my site. Here is an example, check sourcecode for usage.

http://tylerteaching.com/coolbox/

Comment: yeah...only problem is that its not a free license :(

Comment: Ok I updated my answer with a link to my plugin that you can use if you want :)

Should be really straight forward for your students.

Comment: Ok, let me know if you need some styling edits. Basic usage: $(parent of images selector).coolBox();    -    for your HTML you just need img tags with a 'src' and a 'coolbox' attribute. The coolbox attribute is the image you want in the popup, the src is the original image

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using Maginific (http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/), or Pretty Photo (http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/)